# Bypass some of the require() statements in the testing file

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I want to write unit tests for `myFunction()` in the `server.js` file:

Main file: *server.js*

```
const config = require('./configuration'); // <==== local js file that breaks when unit testing
const other = require('some-module'); // <==== some module that is needed and it does not break when testing.

module.exports { myFunction };

function myFunction() {
  // ...
}

function someOtherFunctions() { /*...*/ }
```

Test file: *server.test.js*:

```
const server = require('../server'); // <=== one level up in the folder hierarchy

it('should work', () => {
});
```

**Problem:**

`jest` breaks at `const config = require('./configuration')` and I don't actually need this to test `myFunction`.

However, I need the second: `require('some-module')`.

I need to mock or bypass the first `const config = require('./configuration')`.

**Question:**

How can I only import the `myFunction()` from `server.js` and somehow mock the first `require(...)` statements in the `server.js` ?

Comment: Short answer: add `jest.mock('./configuration')` after the imports

Comment: to the `server.js`? of `server.test.js`? I have tried adding in `server.test.js` but still when it gets to the `require('../server`) line, when I step into it, it tries to load the actual `.configuration`

Comment: Yes, in the test file. It will try to load it in order to generate the mock

Comment: In case the file does not exists you should pass options object with virtual: true - check the docs for it